# Adding numbers in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning angular js and got stuck in the following code:

```
<div ng-app="calculate">
Amount: <input type='text'  data-ng-model='amount' name = 'amount' placeholder = 'Enter amount' >
Charge: <input type='text'  name = 'charge' ng-bind="charge" value="{{ amount | serviceFilter }}" >
Total:  <input type='text'  value= " {{(amount)+ (amount | serviceFilter)}}" name = 'total' >
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('calculate', [])
  .filter('serviceFilter', function( ){
    return function(amount){
      if(angular.isUndefined(amount)){
        charge = '0';
      }else{
        if(isNaN(amount)){
          charge = 'Invalid Data !!!';
        }else{
          if(amount < 1000){
            charge = '200';
          }else{
            charge = '500';
          }
        }
      }
      return charge;
   };
  });
</script>
```

When I enter the amount. I get appropriate charge. But I can't add the amount and charge get the total value.
Let's say:

```
Amount: 1200
Charge: 500
Total : 1700
```

I need to get 1700 but instead I get

```
Total: 1200 500
```

Also I want to know if this is the appropriate way or there is any other better way to do this.
Thankyou

Comment: These are treated as String, convert it to Integer and then perform add operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to do it:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.strNum = '1';
  $scope.parseInt = parseInt
});

app.filter('num', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return parseInt(input, 10);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    {{ strNum }}
    {{ 1*strNum + 1*strNum }}
    {{ parseInt(strNum, 10) + parseInt(strNum, 10) }}
    {{ (strNum|num) + (strNum|num) }}
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when you bind the numbers in to text inputs they are treated as strings so change the text box type to number.

```
<input type='number' data-ng-model='amount' name='amount' placeholder='Enter amount'>
```

and change the string type numbers in filter to int

```
 app.filter('serviceFilter', function( ){
    return function(amount){      
      if(angular.isUndefined(amount)){
        charge = 0;
      }else{
        if(isNaN(amount)){
          charge = 'Invalid Data !!!';
        }else{
           if(amount < 1000){
             charge = 200;
          }else{
            charge = 500;
          }
        }
      }
      return charge;
   };
});
```

or return the `charge` after converting to `int` `return parseInt(charge);` like @LVarayut suggested.

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QOmDXhPZOKS5LpSaZp5v?p=preview)

---

**OR**

do a simple hack to convert these string values to int as,

```
 <input type='text' value="{{ (amount-0) + ((amount | serviceFilter)-0) }}" name='total'>
```

`(amount-0)` and `((amount | serviceFilter)-0)` will return a int, removing `0` will result in a number.

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aDInn847EjDwvbo7LzfV?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use parseInt() in your `serviceFilter` or multiply the string value by one, to convert it to integer.

First option:

```
<script>
  angular.module('calculate', [])
  .filter('serviceFilter', function( ){
    return function(amount){
      var chargeInt;
      if(angular.isUndefined(amount)){
        charge = '0';
      }else{
        if(isNaN(amount)){
          charge = 'Invalid Data !!!';
        }else{
          if(amount < 1000){
            charge = '200';
          }else{
            charge = '500';
          }
        }
      }
      chargeInt = parseInt(charge);
      if (isNaN(chargeInt))
          return charge;
      else 
          return chargeInt;
   };
  });
</script>
```

Second option:

```
<div ng-app="calculate">
Amount: <input type='text'  data-ng-model='amount' name = 'amount' placeholder = 'Enter amount' >
Charge: <input type='text'  name = 'charge' ng-bind="charge" value="{{ amount | serviceFilter }}" >
Total:  <input type='text'  value= " {{(amount)+ 1 * (amount | serviceFilter)}}" name = 'total' >
</div>
```